# run angular compile only when a certian section of a page has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

So I am working on a application that has many many sections that are loaded via jquery ajax, some when it starts and some in response to other sections, and some are even nested. What I wan't to be able to do is say "Oh, the content in `mainContainer` changed?" Well, go compile the code in that section.

The reason is that I would like to be able to put `ui-sref`'s into parts of the code we don't otherwise want to mess with yet. I came up with a solution but it isn't working the way I thought, I added a `$watch` to a custom directive but it fires a bazillion times. Here is the code.

Hopefully some one can explain how to get it to run once only when the content in X `<div>` is changed via one of the many ajax calls that happen, that way I don't need to immediately turn all of the old code into angular and can link to new code that is using angular.

```
app.directive('ngMainContainer', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    console.log("main container directive");
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return elem;
        }, function (val) {
            console.log("Something changed. " + val);
            $timeout(function () {
                $compile(val)(scope);
            }, 0);
        });
    };
});
```

again, I thought putting a watch on the element passed into the directive was the answer however this runs even when I move the mouse and click on the page somewhere outside of the container that was loaded via jquery ajax.

Comment: Have you tried setting a scope var to `elem.html()` and setting a `$watch` on that?

Comment: I get this error "Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/jqLite/nosel - This seems like it shouldn't be hard, obviously I am missing something.

Comment: Please see my answer and the lower edit section of my answer. I tried to address two ways to approach this, one of which includes code that is not dependent on angular for the "injecting" side of things

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that may work for you. I place directive `ngMainContainer` on our element we want to observe the html contents of.

In our controller I append `<p>{{ content }}</p>` which I first `$compile`, then update the scope `var` afterwards like `$scope.html = angular.element(myDiv).html()`. This is where the our directive `$watch` fires.

Here is the full working example. The `<button>` is appending html, but this should emulate the resolution of an ajax call request complete.

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gxrgacg7/)

```
app.directive('ngMainContainer', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('html', function(n, o) {
                if(n !== o) {
                    console.log(elem.contents())
                    // html has changed, do something!
                }
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

    $scope.content = "scope content";

    var myDiv = document.getElementById('main');

    $scope.appendContent = function() { // Replicate Ajax Callback

        var dynamic = $compile('<p ng-cloak>{{ content }}</p>')($scope); // Compile content        
        angular.element(myDiv).append(dynamic);
        $scope.html = angular.element(myDiv).html()
    }
}]);
```

### Edit

Here is a way to do this while appending content to the `<div>` with no notion of angular on the code that is performing the appending

### [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lf2ejkw/)

```
<button id="noAngular" onclick="noAngularAppend()">Append Content - No Angular</button>
```

```
function noAngularAppend() {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('main')).scope().externallyAppend('<p ng-cloak>{{ content }}</p>');
}
```

**Directive Function** (inject `$compile`)

```
scope.externallyAppend = function(element) {
    var node = $compile(element)(scope);
    elem.append(node);
    scope.$apply(scope.html = elem.contents());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sal, I up voted your answer because it ultimately did help me figure this out but in the end it wasn't quite what I was going for.

This is what I ended up with. In the controller for the main application there is function with only two lines in it.

```
 $scope.doReshing = function (element) {
    $compile(angular.element(element))($scope);
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Then in which ever partial that has an ng directive in it right at the top of the document.ready() I put the following.

```
 var removeableContentContainer = $('#removableContentContainer');
 angular.element(removeableContentContainer).scope().doReshing(removeableContentContainer);
```

This does exactly what I want. It lets me take an existing application change virtually nothing about how it works and lets me add ui-srefs in the "old" code and not have to worry about how or when it loads, when it does load, the document.ready() fires and it will tell angular that it needs to compile. This was my goal, you can pull bits of code in at any point in time and have them essentially act as though they were parts of that page with it's controller.